# How can I read images from a folder, starting from image 10 for example with VideoCapture()?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to read a sequence of images from a folder. 
I found:

```
cap=cv2.VideoCapture("in%6d.jpg")
```

But I must start from `image10` and not from the first.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a [repro]. Without it it is hard or impossible to tell what you are trying to do and where the specific issue is.

Comment: I don't think `cv2.VideoCapture()` is what you would want to use to read a **file** — isn't it for capturing images from a camera?

Comment: @martineau See https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture for OP's use case.

Comment: @uneven_mark: Hmm, thanks, unfortunately the documentation is as clear as mud...

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
import os

folder = os.listdir()
folder = sorted(folder)
start_pos = [i for i,x in enumerate(folder) if x == 'image10.jpg'][0]

for i in range(start_pos,len(folder)):
    cap=cv2.VideoCapture(folder[i]) #or whatever the cv2 function is...
```

Comment: Neither is `os.listdir` returning an ordered list, nor does OP want to call `VideoCapture` to be called for each image, see https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture

Comment: Your file system has the list sorted already....but assuming for whatever reason it's sorted descending, it's as easy as adding `.sort` function.